# Why does the SimpleAuth CocoaPod not work with Swift Bridging Header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I cannot seem to get the SimpleAuth CocoaPod to work in a my swift project. I have:

1. created a bridging header file
2. with `#import <SimpleAuth/SimpleAuth.h>` and
3. edited the **swift compiler - code generation section** in build settings

Am I supposed to manually fix the 15 Swift Compiler Errors (mainly 'unknown type name NSString' and 'Expected a type') or is this a sign I am doing something completely wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just went back to several projects with bridging headers to import obj C frameworks and they all appear to have the same issues you have.   It looks like a line by line fix for those.

Comment: This is really not an acceptable answer. A lot of the problems are almost impossible to line by line fix. Is there an updated version of SimpleAuth that actually works for Swift 2.0

Comment: Ah my answer was so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

in your header file

Comment: this did it for me, this should go on the Bridging Header FWIW

Comment: This created additional compiler errors in my Swift code. Ugh.